# Degeneracy in a 2D planar cavity (box potential)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, eigenvalue, density-of-states, normal-modes

Assume a finite 2D planar cavity. One can write the energy of a photon in this cavity as

$$
\begin{equation}
E(k_x, k_y)=\hbar c \sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2},
\end{equation}
$$
where $k_z$ is fixed (hence a (quasi) 2D system). However, I am rather interested in the tranverse wave number $k_{\parallel}^2=k_x^2+k_y^2$. Also, I can write $k_{\parallel}=m \Delta k_{\parallel}$, where $\Delta k_{\parallel}$ is the transverse mode spacing which is fixed, and I am only changing an integer number $m$. So in the end the energy in the system would read:

$$
\begin{equation}
E(m)=\hbar c \sqrt{(m\Delta k_{\parallel})^2+k_z^2},
\end{equation}
$$
where $m=0,1,2...$ with $m=0$ being the lowest energy state.

What is degeneracy in such a system for a given $m$?

**My (intuitive) answer:**

I think the degeneracy should be $g=m+1$, because we need to count in how many ways one can combine the integers $n_x$ and $n_y$ such that $m=n_x+n_y$, (similarly as for 2D Harmonic Oscillator) if we write that $k_x=n_x \Delta k_x$ and $k_y=n_y \Delta k_y$ and assume $\Delta k_x=\Delta k_y$.

**My confusion:**

However, we can also write $k_x^2+k_y^2=n_x^2\Delta k_x^2+n_y^2\Delta k_y^2=m^2 \Delta k_{\parallel}^2 $ and then the problem reduces of finding Pythagorean triplets.

What is the correct way to think about this?